# References for modular linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am looking for references for dealing with modular linear algebra. Specifically, let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb{Z}_k$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $k>1$, can generally be non-prime. Given a system of linear equations

$$ A x = b \mod k, $$

how can I methodically determine

- Whether the system has a solution.
- The dimension of $\text{Col}(A)$, the $\mathbb{Z}_k-$span of the columns of $A$. I understand that if $k$ is not prime then $\text{Col}(A)$ is only a module, and not a vector space. We can still talk about its dimension, correct?
- How to compute a minimal set of vectors $u_1, \dots, u_r$ such that $$\text{Col}(A) \oplus \text{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}_k}\{u_1,\dots, u_r \} = \mathbb{Z}_k^m $$

These questions are easy to deal with when $k$ is prime, since then we just do linear algebra. But when $k$ is not prime, funny things happen since we are not talking about vector spaces anymore, but about modules over rings. For example, matrices may not be reducible to row-echelon form.

Ideally, I would like to understand better how much of the linear algebra I am familiar with goes through. For example, do we still get a rank-nullity theorem in this case?

Comment: "Dimension" is not well-defined for a module, but you can still ask for the structure of the module (as it's a finitely generated abelian group, and those have a rather specific structure). Do you know about the Smith normal form?

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with the Smith normal form, but reading about it now. What if we define dimension of a sub-module as the minimum number of elements which span the sub-module? Why is that not well-defined?

Comment: You can do that, but it's just one of a dozen different concepts of "dimension".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear algebra is not so simple over rings which are not fields. For instance, dimension is no longer a sufficient concept to grasp questions like yours about the column space of a matrix. Since this could be any module, one instead needs to specify which one, using a classification of $\mathbb{Z}_k$-modules as the $k$-torsion abelian groups. Dimension is only well defined for the free modules. In particular, it doesn't make sense to ask for a rank-nullity theorem.

If we try to define dimension as you did in the comments, then the $1\times 1$ matrix $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}/4$ violates the rank-nullity theorem.

Since the classification of finitely generated abelian groups is simple, the above isn't that severe a complication. But you'll be in more trouble on finding a complement to the column space, as you ask in your last question. Again, in the "matrix" $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}/4$, the column space is $2\mathbb{Z}/4$, which is not a direct summand of $\mathbb{Z}/4$. In general, submodules over a ring need not have complements.

As for solving equations, as suggested in the comments one can lift the coefficients to $\mathbb{Z}$, compute the Smith normal form up there, and then reduce modulo $k$. One can also use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to work over fields if $k$ happens to be a product of distinct primes-just solve your problem separately modulo each prime factor.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Suppose that the only non-zero entries in the matrix $A$ are co-prime to $k$. This avoids the troublesome case of the matrix 2 over $\mathbb{Z}/4$. Would your answer to my question be much different?

Comment: Not really. I didn't recall the central fact that a matrix is still invertible if and only if its determinant is invertible in the ring (so, co-prime to $k$.) But it's easy to get a matrix over $\mathbb{Z}/4$ with odd entries but determinant $2$, say.

Comment: Ah I see. One more question. Suppose that Col($A$) is a free submodule, in other words the columns of $A$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Z}_k$. Would it be true then that a complement submodule to Col($A$) exists? If yes, is there a simple way of computing a spanning set for the complement?